# Parent hold pointer to child data member and used the data member function in destructor

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor, destructor

I believe I found a bug for existing code but it actually works. Could you help to verify if my understand is correct?

It is about a parent class holding an object pointer which points to its child class' data object. And in its(the parent) destructor, it uses the object pointer for function accessing. I belive when the parent destructor is called, the child has already been destructed so the object which the parent pointer pointing to is not valid any more. I make a example below:

My question for code below is that if the parent destructor is correct?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class object {
public:

    object(string na):name(na){}

    string get_name(){
        return name;
    }

private:
    string name;
};

class parent {

public:

    ~parent(){
        cout<<"hello"<<endl;
        cout<<mp->get_name();  **//!!!! (is this correct use mp here?)**
    }
protected:
    object* mp;

};


class child:public parent {

public:

    child():m("hello"){
        parent::mp=&m;
    }


private:
    object m;
};

int main()
{

 child a;

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: The elusive "it actually works" is one example of undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I belive when the parent destructor is called, the child has already been destructed

**§ 12.4.8** is gonna become my favorite standard quote.

> After executing the body of the destructor and destroying any automatic objects allocated within the body, a destructor for class X calls the destructors for X's direct non-variant non-static data members(...)

The destructors for members are executed **after** the body of the class dtor, so it's safe to call a member's member function.

## that being said...

In your case, while `mp` is perfectly valid, the value it's pointing to is not. Since `parent` destructor runs after the `child` destructor, the value of which child was the owner is destroyed as well, leaving parent with a dangling pointer.

Comment: Everything you wrote is correct, I mean this is not the whole picture. Yes, destructors for members are executed after the body. But, the parent destructor is executed after this.

Comment: @stas thank you and sorry for the confusion. I'd rather you used the word "incomplete" than "incorrect" :). As in, I thought you saw a factual problem in my answer.

Comment: Yes, wording is not my strength)

Answer (score 1):

It is not correct.

The sequence of destructor calls:

1. `child` destructor
2. `object` destructor (as it is a member of `child` class)
3. `parent` destructor

Look at this: parent keeps a pointer to `object` that is a member of `child` class.

```
child():m("hello"){
    parent::mp=&m;
}
```

So, `object` is already destructed when you try to access it through a pointer in `parent` destructor:

```
~parent(){
    cout<<"hello"<<endl;
    cout<<mp->get_name();  //!!!! this is incorrect
}
```